# Geometric intuition for finite vector spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces, finite-fields

There is a powerful geometric intuition for real vector spaces. Is there any good way of visualizing vector spaces over finite fields?

Comment: There's no easy answer to this question. Everything you know of basic linear algebra carries over to finite fields. But visualizing can be very different. You can read about the Fano plane for a nice example, you will notice that this is very different from your usual visualization. Note that vector spaces over finite fields (in particular $\mathbb{F}_2$) are used extensively in coding theory. You can read about this theory to see some techniques involved.

Comment: I sometimes think of them as being discrete and having their "ends" glued together, instead of extending infinitely. So there is a "wrap around" effect (like in some old video games).

Comment: if the finite field $k$ is cyclic, then a vector space of dimension $n$ over $k$ can thought as a space where elements are points in a discrete $n$ dimensional hyper-cube of size $k$ (this is also how you think to the hamming distance)

Comment: Personally, I was picturing it as sort of like a discrete torus: a set of otherwise disjoint circles passing through the origin, rather than a set of lines passing through the origin. Not sure if this intuition is correct or applicable in any way.